# How to get part of libary from json python

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to make a function that finds the number of subscribers in my channel. I have got the JSON from googles YouTube API but I don't know how to get the number next to subscribers (I am very new to JSON but not python). Could anyone help?

[Picture of the JSON because the URL has my API Key in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arX63.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
python_obj = json.loads(your_json_file)
python_obj['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']
```